# Arcpy.da.UpdateCursor SQL error using Arcmap 10.1 or higher

Tags: arcpy

I am attempting to update the column "DR1cond" (which means driver 1 condition).

Currently, the driver conditions states "drinking" or "sleeping" or "manyotherconditions." I want to update get row so "drinking" = 1 or "sleeping" = 2.

But I am getting an sql error: Here is what I have so far:

```
#Update Cursor to replace current string data with numbers

import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Crash\Fatal03-12.shp'

updateFC = 'DR1cond'

print 'Creating update cursor for',updateFC,' in ',arcpy.env.workspace

updateRows = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(updateFC,["DR1cond"])

#Loop through each Driver conidition and determine replace

print 'Updating DR1cond class field for get row..."

for row in updateRows: 
    ShapeIndex = row[0]
    if(shapeIndex = 'Drinking'):
      DR1cond = "1"
    elif(shapeIndex = 'fatigue' or 'Asleep'):
      DR1cond = "2"
    elif(shapeIndex = 'Normal'):
      DR1cond = "3"
    elif(shapeIndex = 'Drug use'):
      DR1cond = "4" 
    elif(shapeIndex = 'Sick'):
      DR1cond = "5"
    elif(shapeIndex = 'Cell'):
      DR1cond = "6"
    elif(shapeIndex = 'Distracted'):
      DR1cond = "7"
    else(shapeIndex = 'Unknown'):
      DR1cond = "99"
    row[1] = DR1cond
    updateRows.updateRow(row)
print'All done updating'
del updateRows 
del row
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used ArcPy, and I'm not sure if this is related to your problem, but your if/elif/else clauses appear to be invalid syntax.  = is for assignment, == should be used for testing equivalence.  Also, the line which reads `elif(shapeIndex = 'fatigue' or 'Asleep'):` will always trigger the or statement.  I think you want `elif(shapeIndex == 'fatigue' or shapeIndex == 'Asleep'):` instead.

Comment: This might be the error I am getting. I believe the error is in reference to that line of code. But I can not test my code at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

- Use 2 '`=`' for sure.
- Include your new code field in the list of fields when you create your cursor, the cursor won't find `row[1]`.
- And, if the code field is short or other numeric type (that would make sense), drop the '`"`'.